# Automate DVC authentication when using github actions

Tags: authentication, github, github-actions, dvc

I'm using GitHub Actions to run some tests on every push and I need DVC. I'm trying to make this work with the `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` option but when I try to run it, the action get's stuck because it requires manual authentication. Is there a way to go around this and automate the authentication ?

Comment: What kind of DVC remote are you using? 

For many types, you could set up the authentication via environment variables (i.e. `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` for s3) that you can combine with https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Comment: gdrive, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that in order for this to work, I had to switch to using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  Here are the steps I used to setup a Google Service Account with DVC, Google Drive and Github Actions.

### Setup a google cloud platform [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)

A google cloud platform [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) "is a special kind of account used by an application or compute workload, such as a Compute Engine virtual machine (VM) instance, **rather than a person**. A service account is identified by its email address, which is unique to the account."  In this case, the service account for your app to access Google Drive.

1. Go to the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select or Create a project for DVC remote connections.
3. [Enable the Google Drive API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/drive.googleapis.com) by clicking the `ENABLE` button
4. Go to the [Google API Crediential](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) page
5. Click on the `+ Create Credentials` button and then select `Service Account`.
6. Enter a service account name (such as gdrive-api) and a some description (such as "Allows access to the google drive api") then click on the `Create and continue` button.
7. Click `continue` at the "Grant this service account access to the project (optional)" section:  No need to add any accesses.
8. Click `Done` at the "Grant users access to this service account (optional)".  Again, no need to grant any additional accesses.
9. Go to [Service Accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).  You'll see a list of all service accounts for the your GCP project and click on the service account you just created.
10. Click on `key` --> `add key` --> `Create new key` and
11. In the popup window that appears, select JSON as key type, click the `Create` button.  A JSON file of the key you created will download.

### Share access to the Google Drive folder where the DVC repo will live

Still on Google Cloud Platform,

1. Go in IAM --> Service Accounts and click on the service account name you created in the previous section
2. Copy and paste the email associated to this service account.  It should have a form `service_account_name@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
3. Move to Google Drive and share the drive folder where the DVC repo will live with the service account email defined in the last step.

### Set DVC config to use a google service account

1. On your local machine, modify the DVC project config file by typing the following commands.  Change `my_remote` with your actual DVC remote name.

   `dvc remote add --default my_remote gdrive://your_folder_hash`

   `dvc remote modify my_remote gdrive_use_service_account true`

   `dvc remote modify my_remote --local gdrive_service_account_json_file_path path/to/file.json`
2. This will modify the .dvc/config and .dvc/config.local files in your project.
3. Run the command `dvc push`.  If you see no error message, you are done with this step.
4. Push your code to origin on Github

### Setup a Repository Secret

1. In your Github repo, go to Settings -> Secrets and Variables -> Actions
2. Click on the `New repository secret` button.
3. Name the secret to whatever is meaningful to you.
4. Copy and paste the JSON file content you downloaded in the previous section to the `Secret*` text box.
5. Click the `Add Secret` button

### Setup a Github action

To your Github action yaml file, add the following (make sure to change the `YOUR_REPO_SECRET_NAME` to the name of the repo secret you created in the previous step.

```
  - uses: iterative/setup-dvc@v1
  
  - name: Pull data with DVC
    env:
      GDRIVE_CREDENTIALS_DATA: ${{ secrets.YOUR_REPO_SECRET_NAME }}
    run: |
      dvc pull
```

Commit this change and run the Github action!

### References

- [How to Setup a Google Drive DVC Remote](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/how-to/setup-google-drive-remote#using-service-accounts)

Comment: Hi, @Francis, Thanks for your detailed answer. If possible, could you please share your DVC project config file (without any sensitive information of course)? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Francis for this guide. It was exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you for including such a detailed answer here for anyone's future reference (including mine when I inevitably forget what I have to do to set this up).

Answer (score 0):

The following are the code snippets of my `.dvc/config` file and the GitHub Action `.github/workflows/dvc.yml` file that successfully pulled all of the data files with the `.csv.dvc` and `.csv` extensions from my Google Drive account and saved them as a `.zip` GitHub Action artifact file produced during runtime.

The dvc `config` file is as follows.

```
[core]
    remote = storage
['remote "storage"']
    url = gdrive://1sbqUtldKr7oiB-tFv46pHc9DBS6-****
    gdrive_use_service_account = true
```

Create the secrets `GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID`, `GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET`, and `GDRIVE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH` in "Setting", "Secrets and variables", and "Actions" in the GitHub project repository. Copy and paste the secret values in the fields when creating the secrets.

The `.github/workflows/dvc.yml` file is as follows.

```
name: DVC Operations

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev-secret

jobs:
  dvc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Setup DVC
  uses: iterative/setup-dvc@v1

- name: Setup Google Drive credentials
  env:
    GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID }}
    GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET }}
    GDRIVE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON: ${{ secrets.GDRIVE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH }}
  run: |
    echo "$GDRIVE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON" > dvc-remote-connections.json
    dvc remote modify storage gdrive_client_id $GDRIVE_CLIENT_ID
    dvc remote modify storage gdrive_client_secret $GDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET
    dvc remote modify storage gdrive_service_account_json_file_path dvc-remote-connections.json

- name: DVC Pull
  run: dvc pull

- name: Upload data as artifact
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: pulled-data
    path: data/
```